# SQL server group / partition to condense history table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, partition-by

Got a table of dates someone was in a particular category like this:

```
    drop table if exists #category
    create table #category (personid int, categoryid int, startdate datetime, enddate datetime)
    insert into #category 
    select * from 
    (
    select 1 Personid, 1 CategoryID, '01/04/2010' StartDate, '31/07/2016' EndDate union
    select 1 Personid, 5 CategoryID, '07/08/2016' StartDate, '31/03/2019' EndDate union
    select 1 Personid, 5 CategoryID, '01/04/2019' StartDate, '01/04/2019' EndDate union
    select 1 Personid, 5 CategoryID, '02/04/2019' StartDate, '11/08/2019' EndDate union
    select 1 Personid, 4 CategoryID, '12/08/2019' StartDate, '03/11/2019' EndDate union
    select 1 Personid, 5 CategoryID, '04/11/2019' StartDate, '22/03/2020' EndDate union
    select 1 Personid, 5 CategoryID, '23/03/2020' StartDate, NULL EndDate union
    select 2 Personid, 1 CategoryID, '01/04/2010' StartDate, '09/04/2015' EndDate union
    select 2 Personid, 4 CategoryID, '10/04/2015' StartDate, '31/03/2018' EndDate union
    select 2 Personid, 4 CategoryID, '01/04/2018' StartDate, '31/03/2019' EndDate union
    select 2 Personid, 4 CategoryID, '01/04/2019' StartDate, '23/06/2019' EndDate union
    select 2 Personid, 4 CategoryID, '24/06/2019' StartDate, NULL EndDate 
    ) x
    order by personid, startdate
```

I'm trying to condense it so I get this:

| PersonID | categoryid | startdate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/04/2010 | 31/07/2016 |
| 1 | 5 | 07/08/2016 | 11/08/2019 |
| 1 | 4 | 12/08/2019 | 03/11/2019 |
| 1 | 5 | 04/11/2019 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 01/04/2010 | 09/04/2015 |
| 2 | 4 | 01/04/2015 | NULL |

I'm having issues with people like personid 1 where they are in (e.g.) category 5, then go into category 4 and them back into category 5.

So doing something like:

```
select
personid,
categoryid,
min(startdate) startdate,
max(enddate) enddate
from #category
group by 
personid, categoryid
```

gives me the earliest date from category 5's first period, and the latest date from the second period - and means it creates an overlapping period.

So I tried partitioning it with a rownum or rank, but it still does the same thing - i.e. treats the 'category 5's as the same group:

```
select
rank() over (partition by personid, categoryid order by personid, startdate) rank,
c.*
from #category c
order by personid, startdate
```

| rank | personid | categoryid | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 2016-08-07 00:00:00.000 | 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | 2019-04-02 00:00:00.000 | 2019-08-11 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 2019-08-12 00:00:00.000 | 2019-11-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 2019-11-04 00:00:00.000 | 2020-03-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 2020-03-23 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-04-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2015-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-06-23 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 2019-06-24 00:00:00.000 | NULL |

You can see in the rank column that the category 5's start off 1,2,3, miss a row and carry on 4, 5 so obvs in the same partition - I thought that adding the order by clause would force it to start a new partition when the category changed from 5 to 4 and back again.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps and islands problem.  However, if your data tiles perfectly (no gaps) as it does in your example data, then you can do this without any aggregation at all -- which should be the most efficient method:

```
select personid, categoryid, startdate,
       dateadd(day, -1, lead(startdate) over (partition by personid order by startdate)) as enddate
from (select c.*,
             lag(categoryid) over (partition by personid order by startdate) as prev_categoryid
      from #category c
     ) c
where prev_categoryid is null or prev_categoryid <> categoryid;
```

The `where` clause only selects the rows where the category changes.  The `lead()` then gets the *next* start date -- and subtracts 1 for your desired `enddate`.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks. BUT I can't guarantee my data does tile perfectly. Would I be best joining the table back to itself and checking that the start date of 1 row is the end date + 1 of the previous row as well?